# PDF Security by converting into exe through java or c#

Tags: java, c#, pdf

I am trying to create a system to secure pdf files, what i have in mind is that we would convert the pdf into an exe and then send it to the user. The exe would ask for a username and password and then would contact to a server through an api (thats already in place) and eventually will be able to control access to the exe.

So the first part is to create a simple software that should input a pdf and spits out an exe.

Anyone knows on how to do this in c# or java, i dont have any code at the moment just waiting for some inputs from you guys?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply append the encrypted PDF to the previously created exe file itself. It's a working hack, but well, your whole idea seems like a big hack to me.

You could also include the PDF during build of the exe, which is the better way, though it requires a different exe for each PDF.

It is by principle impossible to make this 100% secure, you should be aware of that.

Also: What is wrong with simple password protected PDFs? If you don't trust your uses enough to keep those to themselves, they're probably going to circumvent the exe schema as well.

Comment: Lol, i totally agree with the whole idea being a hack. But there is no other way to avoid it. There are a few proper ways of doing it through Adobe's livecycle access management but it cost around $250,000/year.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to put password protection on your PDF. What happens then is that your client needs to enter a password when he wants to open the document. Then you dont need to Put your PDF in an exe. Also: Its difficult to Send an exe to a client because mail servers dont want to accept attachments as exe. I know you can rename the exe to exx, but its kind of a bad hack.

Comment: well the idea of creating an exe is so that the pdf can connect to an api and only grant access to certain users. So even if they share the passwords, we will have their mac addresses or some unique address to avoid this.

Comment: Another alternative would be to secure the PDF against a certificate issued by the receipient. This then would only allow opening the document if the private key is present. The disadvantage of this approach is that you have to manage maybe many receipient's certificates, and to save the document separately for each and every receipient.